# winsock , how to send an RST,ACK or RST packet

Tags: c++, winsock

I have a winsock server that uses WSAECONNRESET, error code 10054 event. I can perform this by using exit() function but then I have to relaunch my application.

The question is how to kill an established connection and send an rst packet to my server so it would be exactly like processes that take place when I use exit() but not using it. So my app has to keep running but it has to kill connection with RST packet. Basically I want to imitate CTRL+C, or exit() or terminate() process so that RST packet would be sent.

i tried
SO_LINGER socket options in combination with socketclose(); and shutdown(); but it does not cause WSAECONNRESET event.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried SO_LINGER socket options

You need to set it to 'on' with a zero timeout.

> in combination with `socketclose();`

Correct.

> and `shutdown();`

Incorrect. Remove that. It sends a FIN.

> but it does not cause WSAECONNRESET event.

Because of the `shutdown()`. Remove that.

Comment: ill give it a try. But I found out that WSACleanup() also causes this event because it "terminates the use of Winsock 2 dll".

Comment: It will do that for all sockets, but it's overkill. The way above is the standard way to do it.

Comment: ok. i only use one socket so thats okay. but still thanks for help.